# navbar dropdown display in the wrong position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

Im not really a pro in bootstrap. Im trying to set a bootstrap navbar menu with dropdowns, I found on line a great exemple: mega dropdown menu that actually satisfies my needs [the link to mega dropdown menu]`1535`[1](http://codepen.io/organizedchaos/pen/rwlhd) . The problem is, when I try to add another menu element (dropdown), the dropdown is displayed in a wrong position ! (under an other existing menu element). I tried editing the css but I haven't achieved my aim yet !

To test what Im talking about you try to add a drop down menu element and see what happens.
 I would appreciate it if you guys could help me with that.

Comment: Perhaps you did not copy the element correctly, can you provide a demo?

Comment: the link is actually a demo ! check: http://codepen.io/organizedchaos/pen/rwlhd

Comment: for me your codepen seem ok. what's the problem?

Comment: @scaisEdge here's, go to the provided demo, copy a "Dropdown" menu element (with its subs) and paste it just after the last "some link" menu element,you'll find out that the dropdown display in the left (not where it should be) ?

Comment: @Noureddine_UP it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

place the dropdown between last endindgs.

```
    </li>      
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
    -----place any lists-----
    </ul>

</div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
```